# How to add edges in an igraph object from a dictionary

Tags: python, time-complexity, igraph, edges

I'm using a dictionary to represent a set of edges. I'm using the keys of the dictionary to represent edges and the values to represent the weights. The dictionary currently looks like this:

```
{(0, 1): 2, (1, 2): 6, (0, 2): 3}
```

I try this:

```
edges, weights = [], []
for edge, weight in dict_edges.items():
    edges += [edge]
    weights.append(weight)

g.add_edges(edges)
g.es["weight"] = weights
```

But, I don't if there is a faster way or more cleaner to do this.

Anyone have any suggestions how to improve my new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do is perfectly fine; maybe the `for` loop could be replaced with a `zip` call. If you are using Python 2.x::

```
from itertools import izip
edges, weights = izip(*dict_edges.iteritems())
g = Graph(edges, edge_attrs={"weight": weights})
```

If you are using Python 3.x::

```
edges, weights = zip(*dict_edges.items())
g = Graph(edges, edge_attrs={"weight": weights})
```